# Doubt on Scratch org Expiry | Not getting expired if created for 1 day(not sure others)

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I have doubt on scratch org expiry. The scratch org expires in 30 days, there is no doubt. However, if you create a scratch org with 1 or 2 days; you still can log-in to that scratch org after that timeframe.

Steps -

1. Open VS code
2. Create a project
3. Authorize to Dev Hub
4. Create a default scratch org with 1 day expiry.
5. And open default scratch org. - This is getting open even after day 2 or 3.

Is it expected behaviour? or am I missing something?

Comment: I'll confirm in a day or so, but I believe that when you set the expiration to 1 day this actually adds one to today's date and the expiry is at the end of that date (pretty sure that's what I've seen before). This means that the time to live for the scratch org is always rounded up and varies in the range [n..n+1) days from now. However, I'll test this and verify tomorrow if no one else provides an answer first.

Comment: Probably tht could be the reason. Did you try post n+1 day

Comment: I created a 1 day scratch org at around midday. I could still access the scratch org on the following day (the date of expiration), in the AM, but unfortunately I forgot to check again in the afternoon. I can no longer access that scratch org now it's day 2 after the date I created it.

Comment: I guess probably that is the reason. Will check with one more scratch org to be sure.